# Swiftui list padding

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a list of list items in swiftui - and all I want to do is get rid of the list padding. I've found a large number of stack overflow posts covering this.  There are many solutions identified.  I've tried them all - particularly :

```swift
List( data.treeLines ) {
    item in
    TreeLineView( line: item, selectedId: $selectedItem )         
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()).background(Color.yellow)
})
```

Some people say that doesn't work because you need foreach - I've tried

```swift
List() {
    ForEach( data.treeLines ) {
        item in
        TreeLineView( line: item, selectedId: $selectedItem   ).listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()).background(Color.yellow)
    }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()).background(Color.green)
}
```

I've tried .none instead of edge insets..   I've tried EdgeInsets( row:0, top:0, leading:0:, trailing:0) - I've tried -20 leading and trailing.  I've tried putting the directive on the list itself.  I've even tried .listStyle - planliststyle did nothing and the other one I found just gave me an error saying it was only available on iOS.

In every case, the list looks like:

[image: Rendered list]

where I want it to go from edge to edge (and in fact, I also want to get rid of the spacing in between the list items, but that's extra credit)

the one way I did manage to get a change is by doing the following on the list itself:

```swift
.padding(.horizontal, -40)
```

which *does* actually get rid of some of the padding, but also starts putting some of my actual content *underneath* the border, and still seems to have only gotten rid of *half* of the padding. Making that number bigger just shifts my content worse, it doesn't get rid of any more border - it looks like this:

[image: padding change]

so basically - I've read everything I can find, tried every solution, and am now at a bit of a loss :(

note - this is a MacOS app running under macOS 11 - not an IOS app.

Comment: I can get exactly the _look_ I want by not having List - just by having a scrollview, stack and foreach - but then it doesn't automatically update when the list changes :(

Comment: Does this solve you issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204620/how-to-remove-bottom-top-item-padding-from-swiftui-list-in-mac-os?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove bottom/top item padding from SwiftUI List in Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204620/how-to-remove-bottom-top-item-padding-from-swiftui-list-in-mac-os)

Comment: unfortunately not - I tried adding the .frame and the .onreceive - neither had any effect whatsoever :(